# How would i create a second sidebar in Sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

What I want is to have a second sidebar that will show me three lines of the text of the file, which will save me having to open it.

This is a feature that Evernote has:

[image: Evernote snippets feature]

The area pointing to "snippets" is the feature that i want. I would find it so helpful if Sublime had this.

I have searched and I am fairly sure this doesnt exist. So I am wanting to make it myself. So here are my questions;

1. Which file ultimately governs the existence of the existing sidebar?
2. Would this be a package or a plugin? (Im guessing package), and if it is a package, would it be default or user?
3. Is it actually possible to have a second sidebar (or similar), and if so how can i get it to sit to the right of the existing sidebar?

Any other advice on how to go about creating this would be much appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if creating another sidebar is possible nor have I seen any package to do so.

On the other hand, you can do **alt+shift+2(set_layout)** I don't know what the buttons are for OSX. You can find it in Default keymap settings. You can copy that to user keymap, edit the arguments values and bind it to whatever keys you want.

What it will do, is create another window in sublime where you can open other tab with data you wish to have in there.

Example:
[image]

You can also use alt+shift+number, to create more than 2 windows with up to 4. If you wish to do the windows in horizontal position, you can use number 8 and number 9.

Comment: If going down that route have a look at the FileBrowser plugin which is a file browser that works in Sublime Text. Look at the 2nd image down on the FileBrowser page (url follows), it shows something similar to what SEJBR is suggesting and the code of that package might help. BTW FileBrowser is a fork of the Dired plugin.
https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/FileBrowser
https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/dired

Comment: Also just to help with clarifying - SEJBR uses the word 'window' when what he means is columns and rows in the ST layout (Menu-->View-->Layout). He/She doesn't mean a new ST window just to use 2 columns in the layout of one window and to resize so that one of the columns is quite narrow, like a sidebar, as his image shows. I think it's a pretty good solution to your problem although not exactly what you wanted to do (which may not be possible?).

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. Just couldn't get that word at the time of writing :). Thank you.